# Can't save big NSArray to plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, nsarray, plist

I'm saving an array of dictionaries into plist file. I've tested it for an array of about 150 instances and worked fine. Now I have about 350 and the same code isn't working( what can it be caused by?

Isn't working = creates an empty plist.

I'm parsing JSON into the array using TouchJSON
Some elements of some dictionaries have NULL values (if it helps)

Here is the code I use to save data:

```
NSString *filePathDocArray = [DOCUMENTS stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filters.plist"];
        NSString *filePathBundleArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filters" ofType:@"plist"];
        //if there is no current filterlist - download and parse the JSON 
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePathDocArray]) 
        {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:filePathBundleArray toPath:filePathDocArray error:nil];
            NSLog(@"File saved");
        } 
        [APIDownload downloadWithURL:@"url" delegate:self];
```

method called when finishedloading:

```
- (void)APIDownload:(APIDownload*)request 
{   
    CJSONDeserializer *deserializer = [CJSONDeserializer deserializer];
    self.news = [deserializer deserializeAsArray:request.downloadData error:nil];

    NSString *filePathDocArray = [DOCUMENTS stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filters.plist"];
    [self.news writeToFile:filePathDocArray atomically:YES];
    [news release];
    if(TableViewSynthesized) {
        [self.tableViewController release];
        TableViewSynthesized = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it happen that CJSONDeserializer deserializes some of the objects into the types not supported by `NSArray -writeToFile:` ?

Comment: Perhaps use `NSPropertyListSerialization` `dataWithPropertyList:format:options:error:` or `writePropertyList:toStream:format:options:error:` and check for errors. I tend not to use `writeToFile:atomically:` because you can never know why it failed.

Comment: Fixed up the JSON parser to change null objects into @"" and everything works fine!! thank you!